# Problemas no update do banco de dados utilizando PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema no UPDATE com o banco de dados.

Tenho um form que envia os dados para um arquivo php, que realizaria um update em uma tabela do banco de dados MYSQL.

Porém, o update não está realizando a inserção e o mysqli_affected_rows está me retornando um valor (-1).

Vou postar o código do formulário e do arquivo php.

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 
 //CHAMANDO O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
 require_once "conexao/conexao.php"; 
 
  
 //CHAMANDO O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
 require_once "banco-de-dados/tela-atividade-extra/create.php"; 
   
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Sistema - JCA</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=devide-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
  
  <link href="css/estilo-atividade-extra.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- ARQUIVO CSS DA PÁGINA -->
  <link href="_bootstrap-4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- ARQUIVO CSS DO BOOTSTRAP -->
   
</head>


<body>
  
  
  
  
  <div class="container-fluid">
   
   <header>
   
    <h1 class="alinhar-texto-no-centro">Atividade Extra</h1>
    <p class="alinhar-texto-no-centro"><i>"Uma mente que se abre a uma nova idéia jamais voltará ao seu tamanho original"</i></p>
    
   </header>
   
   <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" id="formulario">
     
     <!-- DIV COM O FORMULÁRIO DE LOGIN -->
         
      <form action="banco-de-dados/tela-atividade-extra/update.php" method="post" id="formulario-login-sistema">
              
       <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
        <label for="colaborador">Colaborador:</label>
        <select name="colaborador" id="colaborador" class="input form-control">
         <option><?php echo utf8_decode($_SESSION["nome"]) ?></option>    
        </select>
        
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-1">
        <label for="atividade">Qual será a atividade ?</label>
        <select name="atividade" id="atividade" class="input form-control">
         <?php
         while($registros = $query_pegar_atividades -> fetch_assoc())
         {
          $ativ = utf8_decode($registros['ATIVIDADE']);
             
          echo "<option>$ativ</option>";
                 
         }
         ?>         
        </select>
       </div>
       
       <!-- LINHA -->
       
       <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
       
        <label for="data-vencimento">Qual é a data de vencimento:</label>
        <input type="date" name="data-vencimento" id="data-vencimento" class="input form-control">
        
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1">
        <label for="designou-atividade">Quem designou a atividade?</label>
        <select name="designou-atividade" id="designou-atividade" class="input form-control">
         <option>CLIENTE</option>
         <?php
         while($registros = $query_pegar_designador -> fetch_assoc())
         {
          $usu = utf8_decode($registros['usuario']);
             
          echo "<option>$usu</option>";
                 
         }
         ?>    
        </select>
       </div>

       <!-- LINHA -->
       
       <div class="col-lg-12 alinhar-texto-no-centro" id="selecionar-empresas">
        <h3 class="alinhar-texto-no-centro">Selecionar Empresa</h3>
       

       
        <!-- CAMPO CODIGO DA EMPRESA -->
        <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
        
         <label for="codigo-empresa">COD</label>
         <select name="codigo-empresa" id="codigo-empresa" class="input form-control">
          <?php
          while($registros = $query_pegar_cod -> fetch_assoc())
          {
           $emp = $registros['COD'];
              
           echo "<option>$emp</option>";
                  
          }
          ?>   
         </select>
         
        </div>
             
        <!-- CAMPO EMPRESA -->
        <div class="form-group col-lg-5">
         <label for="empresa">Empresa</label>
         <select name="empresa" id="empresa" class="input form-control">
          <?php
          while($registros = $query_pegar_empresa -> fetch_assoc())
          {
           $empr = utf8_decode($registros['EMPRESAS']);
              
           echo "<option>$empr</option>";
                  
          }
          ?>     
         </select>
        </div>
        
        <!-- CAMPO TRIBUTAÇÃO -->
        <div class="form-group col-lg-5">
         <label for="tributacao">Tributação</label>
         <select name="tributacao" id="tributacao" class="input form-control">
          <?php
           while($registros = $query_pegar_tributacao -> fetch_assoc())
           {
            $empre = utf8_decode($registros['TRIBUTACAO']);
               
            echo "<option>$empre</option>";
                   
           }
          ?>        
         </select>
        </div>
        
        
        <!-- CAMPO POSSUIR ARQUIVOS -->
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-9" id="lista-empresas" style="display:inline">
         <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="radio">
           <label>
            <input type="radio" name="empresas-filtro" id="empresas-filtro" value="sim" class="form-control" checked>Minhas
           </label>
          </div>
          
          <div class="radio">
           <label>
            <input type="radio" name="empresas-filtro" id="empresas-filtro" value="nao" class="form-control">Todas
           </label>
          </div>
         </div>         
        </div>

        
        
        
       </div>

       <!-- LINHA -->
       
        <!-- CAMPO DETALHES -->
        
        <div class="form-group col-lg-12" id="destalhes">
         <label for="destalhes-da-atividade">Detalhes sobre a atividade</label>
         <textarea class="form-control" name="destalhes-da-atividade" id="destalhes-da-atividade" style="resize:none" maxlength="500" rows="10" placeholder="Descreva detalhes sobre a atividade">
         </textarea>
        </div>

       <!-- LINHA -->

        <!-- CAMPO QUANTIDADE DE PROCESSOS -->
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
         <label for="quantidade-processos">Quantidade de Processos: </label>
         <input class="form-control" type="number" name="quantidade-processos" id="quantidade-processos" maxlength="40" required>
        </div>
        
        <!-- CAMPO POSSUIR ARQUIVOS -->
        <div class="form-group col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-4" id="possui-arquivo" style="display:inline">
         <label for="possui-arquivo">Possui Arquivo ?</label>
         <div class="form-inline">
          <div class="radio">
           <label>
            <input type="radio" name="possui-arquivo" id="opcao-radio" value="S" class="form-control" checked> SIM
           </label>
          </div>
          
          <div class="radio">
           <label>
            <input type="radio" name="possui-arquivo" id="possui-arquivo" value="N" class="form-control"> NÃO
           </label>
          </div>
         </div>         
        </div>

        
        <!-- LINHA -->
        
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-9 form-group">
         <input name="salvar-atividade-extra" id="salvar-atividade-extra" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Salvar">
        </div>
       
      </form>
      
    </div>  
      
       
   </div>
   
   
   
  </div>
    
  <script src="_jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> <!-- ARQUIVO JQUERY -->
  
</body> <!-- FIM DO BODY -->
</html> <!-- FIM DO HTML -->


<!-- Arquivo PHP de inserção no banco de dados  -->

<?php
 //CHAMANDO O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO COM O BANCO DE DADOS
 require_once "../../conexao/conexao.php"; 
 
 session_start();
 date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+3');
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "", "pt_BR.utf-8");
 
 $departamento_usuario = $_SESSION["departamento-usuario"] ;
 $empresa_origem_usuario = $_SESSION["empresa-origem-usuario"];
  
 if(isset($_POST["salvar-atividade-extra"])) //REALIZA A AÇÃO SE O BOTÃO "ENVIAR" FOR ACIONADO
 {
  //PREENCHE AS VARIÁVEIS COM OS DADOS VINDOS DOS CAMPOS DO FORMULÁRIO
  
  $colaborador = utf8_decode($_POST["colaborador"]);
  $atividade   = utf8_decode($_POST["atividade"]);
  $data_vencimento = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_POST["data-vencimento"])); 
   
  $designou_atividade  = utf8_decode($_POST["designou-atividade"]);
  $codigo_empresa = $_POST["codigo-empresa"];
  $empresa   = utf8_decode($_POST["empresa"]);
  $tributacao = utf8_decode($_POST["tributacao"]);
  $empresas_filtro  = utf8_decode($_POST["empresas-filtro"]);
  $destalhes_atividade  = utf8_decode($_POST["destalhes-da-atividade"]);
  $quantidade_processos = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'quantidade-processos', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
  $possui_arquivos  = utf8_decode($_POST["possui-arquivo"]);
  
  //VALORES FIXOS 
  
  //COMPARANDO A DATA DO CAMPO COM A DATA ATUAL
  $hoje = date("d-m-y");
  if($data_vencimento < $hoje)
  {
   $status = "VENCIDO";
  }
  else
  {
   $status = "PENDENTE";
  }
  
  
  //CONFIGURANDO A VARIÁVEL CONFERENCIA
  
  if($possui_arquivos == "S")
  {
   $conferencia = "A CONFERIR";
  }
  else 
  {
   $conferencia = "NÃO POSSUI ARQUIVO";
  }
  
  
  
 } 
 
 
 $update_one = "INSERT INTO tbl_atividades(COD, EMPRESAS, TRIBUTACAO, RESPONSAVEL, DESIGNADOR, TIPO_ATIVIDADE, DT_VENCIMENTO, STATUS, DETALHES, EXTRA_URGENTE_COMUM, VISUALIZADO, ATUALIZADO, ARQUIVO, DEPARTAMENTO, EMPRESA_ORIGEM, CONFERENCIA, QNTD_PROCESSOS) 
 VALUES('$codigo_empresa','$empresa','$tributacao','$colaborador','$designou_atividade','$atividade','$data_vencimento','$status','$destalhes_atividade','E','S','S','$possui_arquivos','$departamento_usuario','$empresa_origem_usuario','$conferencia','$quantidade_processos')";
  
 $update_atividades_extras = mysqli_query($conecta, $update_one);
 
 $affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($conecta);
 
 if($affected_rows > 0)
 {
  header("location:../../form-atividade-extra.php");
  
 }
 
 print_r($update_one);
 
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você pegar a instrução SQL do seu `$update_one` e executar direto no banco, ocorre algum erro ? Adicione também informações sobre a tabela para entendermos melhor a situação.

Comment: Adicionei a imagem da tabela em que necessito fazer inserção dos dados.

Comment: Ok.. e tentou executar direto no banco a instrução ? Deu erro ?

Comment: Consegui resolver, 8biT. Era um problema com as datas. Esse banco (que hoje é em MySQL) já foi em ACESS. Foi feito uma migração para o MySQL. Então ele veio com algumas falhas. As datas do banco, por exemplo, estão no formato (y:d:m) e eu estava inserindo no formato (d:m:y). Então estava havendo uma incompatibilidade na hora do insert, na comparação entre elas. Mas mesmo assim, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, pela exemplo da sua tabela que você postou, o seu campo "codigo" (que estou imaginando que é a sua PRIMARY KEY) esta como NULL, provavelmente ele deveria ser NOT NULL e AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: Sim, esse banco eu peguei meio que com bonde andando. Como o rapaz que administra o banco de dados, na empresa, fez a transição do ACESS para o MySQL, acabou que o campo "codigo" não veio como chave primária para o MySQL(Mas no Acess era). Mas eu já resolvi o problema. O problema era a data, que veio do acess para o MySQL no formato (Y:D:M) e eu estava inserindo no formulário para o PHP no formato (D:M:Y). Então estava havendo uma incompatibilidade quando elas eram comparadas.